# $scope variable not updating in view after broadcast event from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ejs, angular-directive

I have read similar questions and I can't put my finger on why this is not updating. I can get logs of the scope variable updating on the catch events. But it's not updating the view. So it populates with "test", but will not update when $scope.keyPressed is being updated.

the directive

```
app.directive('keypressEvents', [
  '$document',
  '$rootScope',
  function($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function() {
        $document.bind('keypress', function(e) {
          console.log('Got keypress:', e.which);
          // console.log('document', $document)
          $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress:' + e.which, e);
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

the controller

```
$scope.keyPressed = 'test';
$scope.$on('keypress:13', function(onEvent, keypressEvent) {
          $scope.keyPressed = 'Enter';
          console.log($scope.keyPressed);
        });
        // For listening to all keypress events
        $scope.$on('keypress', function(onEvent, keypressEvent) {
          if (keypressEvent.which === 120) {
            $scope.keyPressed = 'x';
          }
          else {
            console.log('else' ,keypressEvent);
            $scope.keyPressed = 'Keycode: ' + keypressEvent.which;
          }
        });
```

the view

```
<div data-keypress-events>
    {{keyPressed}}
</div>
```

The controller for the view is dictated by the route provider when it loads the partial.

```
.when('/feed/:url', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/eventWall-feed',
            controller: 'eventWallFeedController'
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$on` and `$broadcast` do not call `$apply` therefore you need to wrap `$scope.keypPressed` in an `$apply` like

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.keyPressed = 'x';
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. What really messed me up was I got the directive snippet from another question. And it just ruined me why it could not update. Why do other $scope variables get updated. Like in a callback for an ajax call I can update a $scope variable on the .then function and it will update. But here I have to call $apply?

Comment: I think because $broadcast and $on have the potential to be run many times and it would hinder performance if it ran a digest cycle every time. That is my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a $scope.$apply() to the end of the keypress function.